# Retrieving data which doesn't exist in the other table

Tags: laravel-5

I have two tables SCHOLAR and MEMBER table. I want to display list of scholars from Scholar table which scholar_id doesn't found in Member table. But the result of my Second dd is empty which actually it has data in database. What am i doing wrong?I think my code is fine.

```
public function list()
{
    $scholars = Member::all();
    $scholar_ids = [];
    foreach ($scholars as $scholar) {
    array_push($scholar_ids, $scholar->scholar_id);
}

$scholar_exits = Scholar::where('scholar_id','=', $scholar_ids)->get();

<!-- First -->
dd($scholar_ids);
<!-- Second -->
dd($scholar_exits);

}

<!-- First dd result -->
array:7 [▼
  0 => 7
  1 => 8
  2 => 12
  3 => 13
  4 => 14
  5 => 15
  6 => 16
]

<!-- Second dd result -->

Collection {#275 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Hope anyone can help me here.

Comment: 1) I might suggest your use `array_pluck` instead or `foreach` and `array_push`. 2) I guess `Scholar::whereIn('id', $scholar_ids)->get();` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
public function list()
{
    $members = Member::all();
    $members = $members->toArray();
    $scholar_ids = array_pluck($members, 'scholar_id');
}

//Are you sure you do not want to refer to 'id' instead of 'scholar_id'?
$scholar_exits = Scholar::whereIn('scholar_id', $scholar_ids)->get();

}
```

Comment: yes sir i use scholar_id instead of id. but Sir thank you for sharing your ingenuity. Now its working

Answer (score 0):

```
public function list()
{
    $scholars = Member::get(['scholar_id'])->toArray();

    if(!is_null($scholars)) $scholars = array_flatten($scholars);
    else $scholars = [];

    $scholar_exits = Scholar::whereNotIn('scholar_id', $scholars)
                     ->get();
}
```